# if condition doesnt execute in php after assigning db value to textbox and the fetching i on next page

Tags: php

I am fetching value from DB and assigning value to textbox on same page

```
<input type='text' name='sr1' value='<?php echo $row['value']?>'>
```

On next page trying to fetch the value from same textbox .

```
$sr1 = $_POST['sr1'];
```

when I print the variable using echo, value is getting printed as 'Yes'.
but when start comparing it in 'if condition' always else is getting executed.

```
if($sr1=='Yes')
  echo 'Yes';  
else 
    echo 'No';
```

Comment: `var_dump($sr1);`

Comment: getting op as :- string(6)"Yes"  as the field size in db is 6

Comment: Is the value for $row['value'] coming from a database query?

Comment: yes the value is comming from db query

Comment: check for the value stored in db contains white spaces?

Comment: yes DB values contains 3 whitespace after

Comment: it worked thank u @Omi; @ SpacePhoenix; @u_mulder ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `var_dump($sr1)` is giving output as  `string(6)"Yes"` that means value in you db contains white spaces. Either you need to trim white spaces before storing value into db or use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) while comparing value.

`$sr1 = trim($_POST['sr1']);`

It will remove white spaces around `$_POST['sr1']` & gives you string `Yes` & your comparison will get work.